# Serving content from jar using webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, static-files

I use Spring REST Docs to generate documentation. Then I put it inside fat jar.

Location of file within jar:

```
/BOOT-INF/classes/static/docs/index.html
```

How I can serve such file using webflux?

I've tried to put `resources` in `RouterFunctionDsl`:

```
internal class MyRoutes() {

    fun router() = router {
        "/foo".nest {
            resources("/docs", ClassPathResource("docs/"))
        }
    }
}
```

unfortunately with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I don't need to add any `resources`. Serving static files works out of box (in Spring Boot)

According to the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-webflux-static-content

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo in your code sample, it should probably be

```
ClassPathResource("static/docs/")
```

I guess you were confused by the default locations used by Spring Boot to serve static locations. If you look at [the Spring Boot common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) section in the reference documentation, you'll see that the default value for the resource locations in WebFlux and MVC are the following:

```
classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/
```

So the `/static` prefix is not automatically added, it's a Spring Boot convention.

Comment: According to the javadoc of `ClassPathResource`: `Supports resolution as File if the class path resource resides in the file system, but not for resources in a JAR.`

Comment: You mean you’ve tried this solution and it doesn’t work?

Comment: Yes, I've double checked if file is present within a jar file `/BOOT-INF/classes/static/docs/index.html` and my path is: `"/".nest { resources("/docs", ClassPathResource("static/docs/")) }`

Comment: Ok, It seems that no router function is needed. I've just put my file in `/public` and it was working out of the box